# XSL Concatnate Number to Dollar amount

Tags: xslt, concatenation

my XML looks like this

```
<SAC05>7100</SAC05>
```

I need to format `<SAC05>` from `7100` to `71.00` in the display.

I've tried this:

```
$<xsl:value-of select="format-number(SAC05, '###,###,###.##')"/>
```

But it comes back at `$7100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format-number()` function formats the input value into the specified format. Since the input value is `7100` it will try to convert it into `7100.00` and not `71.00`.

You need to divide the input by `100` and then apply the formatting. Also you can make use of the `concat()` function to prefix `$` symbol to the output.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$', format-number(SAC05 div 100, '###,###,###.00'))" />
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much this resolved my issue.   Greatly appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Can I ask one more question?  Since you seem to understand XSL & XML.   I need to take the <SAC05> and total them.  There might be 1 or multiple <SAC05> in the code.

Comment: For summing up the values of `<SAC05>`, you can use the `sum()` function. E.g. `<xsl:value-of select="sum(SAC05)" />` in a proper context will provide the sum. It is not a good practice to add code within comments hence I am restricting myself to just provide some direction. You can look up some XSL tutorials on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) for more details and features of XSLT.